# I am trying to run a df.query with a column named class involved and am receiving either syntax or error stating that class is a reserved keyword

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter the data frame column `"class"` for cells labeled `"suv"`:

```
dataframe_calc_suv = dataframe_calc.query('dataframe_calc['class'] == "suv"')
suv_cty = dataframe_calc_suv["cty"].mean()
```

I tried this and it gives syntax error, but when I do a simple print it works, like this:

```
print(dataframe_calc['class'])
```

If I simply put

```
dataframe_calc_suv = dataframe_calc.query('class == "suv"')
```

I get an ungodly error message.

The error message looks like this:

```
>>> dataframe_calc_suv = dataframe_calc.query('class == "suv"')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/arturoaltamirano808/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3469, in query
    res = self.eval(expr, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/arturoaltamirano808/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3599, in eval
    return _eval(expr, inplace=inplace, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/arturoaltamirano808/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/eval.py", line 342, in eval
    parsed_expr = Expr(expr, engine=engine, parser=parser, env=env)
  File "/Users/arturoaltamirano808/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py", line 798, in __init__
    self.terms = self.parse()
  File "/Users/arturoaltamirano808/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py", line 817, in parse
    return self._visitor.visit(self.expr)
  File "/Users/arturoaltamirano808/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py", line 397, in visit
    raise e
  File "/Users/arturoaltamirano808/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expr.py", line 393, in visit
    node = ast.fix_missing_locations(ast.parse(clean))
  File "/Users/arturoaltamirano808/Desktop/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 47, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    class =="suv"
          ^
SyntaxError: Python keyword not valid identifier in `numexpr` query
```

I am new to SO and python in general. Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: The last one should be the correct way. Please add the error message you are getting.

Comment: I have added the error message I am receiving, thanks for the help.

Comment: Okay, so as the error message says, `class` is a python keyword. `query` has an eval mechanism based on `numexpr`, and python reserved keywords are not valid variable names in python. You can instead use `dataframe_calc_suv = dataframe_calc[dataframe_calc['class'] == "suv"]` or if possible change the column name `class` to `classes` or something like that, then you can use `query`.

Comment: This solved the problem, thank you. I guess brackets need to be used instead of parenthesis in instances like this.